# Can I use automate data creation using the name of my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I will soon have many data frames, e.g.:

```
Plot_1 <- read_excel("QA_Reporting_Plot_1.xlsx", sheet = "Species_mismatch_list")
Plot_2 <- read_excel("QA_Reporting_Plot_2.xlsx", sheet = "Species_mismatch_list")
Plot_3 <- read_excel("QA_Reporting_Plot_3.xlsx", sheet = "Species_mismatch_list")
Plot_4 <- read_excel("QA_Reporting_Plot_4.xlsx", sheet = "Species_mismatch_list")
```

e.g. Plot_1:

```
    Feature     Related_table      Species                                     
     1 Veg plot    Vascular           Festuca rubra                                  
     2 Veg plot    Vascular           Bromus secalinus   
     3 Veg plot    Vascular           Lolium perenne                              
     4 Pond        Tree               Quercus
```

I am binding these all into one using dplyr

All_plots <- dplyr::bind_rows(Plot_1, Plot_2, Plot_3, Plot_4)

However, in this 'All_plots' data frame, I still want to know which line comes from which original data frame. Is there a way I can generate a column called Plot_reference which for each row automatically pulls through the name of the original dataframe? (i.e. Plot_1, Plot_2, Plot_3). I want this to be automated because I may have upwards of 40 or 50 plots.

Thanks in advance.

I haven't been able to figure anything out which would generate the new data based on the string in the dataframe title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store (or generate) a vector of the file paths you want to read in and then use `purrr::map` to read in the files. `list_rbind` creates one data.frame, and the `names_to` argument adds a column with the name with the file from which the data comes from:

```
file_list <- c("QA_Reporting_Plot_1.xlsx",
               "QA_Reporting_Plot_2.xlsx",
               "QA_Reporting_Plot_3.xlsx",
               "QA_Reporting_Plot_4.xlsx")

plot_names <- stringr::str_extract(file_list, "Plot_[0-9]{1,2}")

library(purrr)

file_list %>% 
  set_names(nm = plot_names) %>% 
  map(function(plot_name) {
    read_excel(plot_name, sheet = "Species_mismatch_list")
  }) %>% 
  list_rbind(names_to = "plot_name")
```

Comment: I have no idea, I also only recently saw it and have used map_dfr so far, I find it quite handy. It also directly has the `.id` argument to create the name column. The tidyverse API really changes a lot

Comment: Hi @starja, thanks for this. It looks very promising. However, in my real data (data provided was dummy), my plot names are both numerical and alphabetical. I.e. Plot_TF8012. How can I tweak the above to allow for extracting of this string with both numbers and letters? Many thanks

Comment: the below answers my above question so this is now solved ```Plot_refs <- stringr::str_extract(file_list, "Plot_[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,4}")```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

# list all the files in the working directory with the format "QA_Reporting_Plot_\\d+.xlsx"
files <- list.files(pattern = "QA_Reporting_Plot_\\d+.xlsx")

# get them all in one tibble
map_dfr(files, ~ read_excel(.x, sheet = "Species_mismatch_list") |> mutate(name = str_remove_all(.x, "QA_Reporting_|\\.xlsx")))
```